# Changing the font in Aquamacs?

Tags: macos, emacs, lisp, aquamacs

I've recently had a need to do a bit of lisp editing and I found the nifty Ready Lisp package for OS X, which is great, except Aquamacs automatically uses a proportional font (which is idiotic, IMHO) and I want to change it to a monospace font. However, I'm not really much of an EMACS user, and the preferences menu in Aquamacs is less than clear on where and how one might make such a change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I have in my .emacs for OS X:

```
(set-default-font "-apple-bitstream vera sans mono-medium-r-normal--0-0-0-0-m-0-mac-roman")
```

Now, I'm not sure Bitstream Vera comes standard on OS X, so you may have to either download it or choose a different font. You can search the X font names by running `(x-list-fonts "searchterm")` in an ELisp buffer (e.g. `*scratch*` - to run it, type it in and then type `C-j` on the same line).

Answer (score 11):

In Aquamacs 2.1, you can set the font through Options->Appearance->Font for Text Mode...   That brings up the standard font chooser window, choose the font you like.  Then, when you exit out of emacs (C-x C-c) you'll be prompted to save options, hit "y".

Answer (score 6):

From the [EmacsWiki Aquamacs FAQ](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/AquamacsFAQ#toc7):

> To change the font used to display the
> current frame, go to the font panel.
> You can do this with the keystroke
> Apple-t, or via the menu: Options →
> Show/Hide → Font Panel. Once there,
> select the font you want.
>
> To make the current frame’s font the
> default, go to Options → Frame
> Appearance Styles. Select “use current
> style for foo mode”, where foo is the
> mode of the current frame (e.g.,
> foo=text for text mode), to use the
> current style (including the font, but
> also any other changes you’ve made to
> the frame’s style) for all files of
> this type. Select “use current style
> as default” to use the current style
> for all files for whose major mode no
> special style has been defined.

There are also recommendations for monospaced fonts - Monaco or "Vera Sans Mono".

Comment: This is the best answer.  Like others, I'm using DejaVu Sans Mono, which is an extension of Bitstream Vera Sans Mono.

Answer (score 2):

this is the one I use:

```
 -apple-DejaVu_Sans_Mono-medium-normal-normal-*-12-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
```

You can set it in .emacs file like:

```
(set-default-font "-apple-DejaVu_Sans_Mono-medium-normal-normal-*-12-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1")
```

You can download it from [dejavu-fonts.org](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/index.php?title=Download)

Answer (score 1):

Fast forward a decade, for recent Aquamacs like ver 3.3 please see the nice solution for setting a fixed-width by default at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45135/change-permanently-font-size-in-aquamacs

Here's the relevant bit for those who are REALLY impatient but please go upvote that answer, user @nega deserves credit here

```
(when window-system
  (setq initial-frame-alist nil)   ;; Undo Aquamacs forced defaults
  (setq default-frame-alist nil)   ;; Undo Aquamacs forced defaults
  (aquamacs-autoface-mode -1)      ;; Use one face (font) everywhere
  (set-frame-font "Menlo-12")      ;; Set the default font to Menlo size 12
  ;;(set-default-font "Menlo-12")  ;; This would do the same.
)
```